# cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath always equal to 0

Tags: ios

I don't get it. The cellForRowAtIndexPath function's indexPath parameter is always 0. I currently have 7 rows in my table. What my table shows is 7x the first table row. What could cause the indexPath to always be zero?

```
@implementation SitesViewController

@synthesize sites, siteCell;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [sites count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SiteCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SiteCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = siteCell;
        self.siteCell = nil;
    }
    Site *site = [sites objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    UILabel *siteNameLabel;
    siteNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    siteNameLabel.text = site.siteName;

    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[DigMateAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Sites" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];
    NSError *error;
    sites = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have 7 rows and I assume 1 section then you should get record from array based on row index, not section. So the following line in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
Site *site = [sites objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

should be:

```
// Use indexPath's row instead of section!
Site *site = [sites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```